# UITableView not showing data, cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having trouble with UITableView
The problem is that nothing is shown when I run the SidePanelViewController. What am I missing? I am not getting any errors, just an empty tableview.

SidePanelViewController
[image: Storyboard SidePanelViewController]

and here's my code

```
class SidePanelViewController : BackgroundViewController {

var delegate: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name2Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: Me.read(Me.Key.profileImage) as! String))
    nameLabel.text = Me.read(Me.Key.displayName) as? String
    name2Label.text = Me.read(Me.Key.displayName2) as? String

    let adapter = SidePanelTableAdapter(sidePanels: Constants.menu)
    adapter.tableView = menuTableView
    menuTableView.delegate = adapter
    menuTableView.dataSource = adapter
    menuTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

I create new class called SidePanelTableAdapter implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate

```
class SidePanelTableAdapter: NSObject {

var tableView: UITableView!
var sidePanels: [SidePanel]
var total = 0

init(sidePanels: [SidePanel]) {
    self.sidePanels = sidePanels
    total = sidePanels.count
    print ("total \(total)")
}
}
extension SidePanelTableAdapter: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if isExpanded[indexPath.row] {

    }
}
}
extension SidePanelTableAdapter: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("count \(self.total)")
    return self.total
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("ih wow")
    let row  = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView
        .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SidePanelTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SidePanelTableViewCell
    cell.navImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: sidePanels[row].iconUrl))
    cell.navTitle.text = sidePanels[row].name
    print("get \(cell)")
    return cell
}
}
```

i have 8 data. to make sure, i print data  numberOfRowsInSection, 
in log the output is right -> "count 8".

But cellForRowAtIndexPath not called. to make sure again i print text in that method -> "ih wow". but "ih wow" does not appear on the log.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: have you assigned your viewcontroller as the delegate and datasource for your tableview in the interface builder?

Comment: @BlakeLockley i tried that method, still not working.

Comment: Run and check TableView's size. TableView will not call its datasource when its height or weigh is zero

Comment: @VietHung did you mean width? i double check both, heigth or width. not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I just solve this, thanks @Matt for the information.
Like matt said. adapter destroyed after method viewDidLoad() called.

So i change my code from

```
class SidePanelViewController : BackgroundViewController {

var delegate: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name2Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: Me.read(Me.Key.profileImage) as! String))
    nameLabel.text = Me.read(Me.Key.displayName) as? String
    name2Label.text = Me.read(Me.Key.displayName2) as? String

    let adapter = SidePanelTableAdapter(sidePanels: Constants.menu)
    adapter.tableView = menuTableView
    menuTableView.delegate = adapter
    menuTableView.dataSource = adapter
    menuTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

to this:

```
class SidePanelViewController : BackgroundViewController {

var delegate: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name2Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!

let adapter = SidePanelTableAdapter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: Me.read(Me.Key.profileImage) as! String))
    nameLabel.text = Me.read(Me.Key.displayName) as? String
    name2Label.text = Me.read(Me.Key.displayName2) as? String

    adapter.tableView = menuTableView
    menuTableView.delegate = adapter
    menuTableView.dataSource = adapter
    menuTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

maybe because I am android developer before, and new in iOS and I still use the pattern of java.
I guess I should learn more from you matt.
Thank you every one.

Answer (score 3):

You are saying this:

```
let adapter = SidePanelTableAdapter(sidePanels: Constants.menu)
adapter.tableView = menuTableView
menuTableView.delegate = adapter
menuTableView.dataSource = adapter
menuTableView.reloadData()
```

Now think about what happens at the moment that code ends. `adapter` is a local variable, a SidePanelTableAdapter object in a local variable. The code ends, the local variable is destroyed, *and the SidePanelTableAdapter is destroyed*. Thus you are left with a view (the table view) with no SidePanelTableAdapter to control it. Your SidePanelTableAdapter code never runs because your SidePanelTableAdapter *doesn't exist*.

Perhaps what you want to do here is assign `adapter` into a *property* of SidePanelViewController so that it *persists*.

Comment: So you mean, i must have TableViewController and then in SidePanelViewController i add TableViewController as a child?

Comment: Sorry, I need to revise my answer. Forget everything I said.

Comment: Okay, sorry, revised my answer. Now see if that makes sense.

Comment: However I still don't understand how your storyboard is structured. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Oh.
After user login, scene go to SidePanelViewController. Inside SidePanelViewController i have TableViewController.

Comment: You can't put one view controller inside of another, except by using a Container View. That is why I don't understand what your screen shot is a picture of. Moreover, if you have a table view controller in your storyboard, then I don't understand what SidePanelTableAdapter is for, since it is _not_ a table view controller. That mismatch is very weird.

Comment: Thanks Matt. i just solve the problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979192/uitableview-not-showing-data-cellforrowatindexpath-not-called/35981536#35981536